# With vb.net, how can I split this filename/string?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim suffix As String = "_version"
```

I have a file called "Something_version1.jpg"

I need to split this so that I get "Something_version"

The following gets me "1.jpg"

```
filename = filename.Split(New String() {suffix}, StringSplitOptions.None)(1)
```

And the following gets me "Something"

```
filename = filename.Split(New String() {suffix}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0)
```

But what I need is "Something_version"

The suffix is dynamic, and can change.

Hope this is easier than I'm making it.

Thank you.

Comment: And you don't care about the "1.jpg" part at all, then? So all you want is the suffix and the part before the suffix? Sounds like split is overkill, but if you really want split, you can do what you have above (the second one) to get the prefix, and simply concatenate the prefix and suffix to get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm not sure I understand how to leverage your suggestion because of the number to the right of the suffix. It's possible I'm having a brain dead moment.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman Please tell me why I didn't think of this? Oh my gosh...

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman Please add as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Oh; nevermind my comment! I didn't read enough.

Comment: Does what you want to disregard always start with numbers or can there be other characters?

Comment: Always numbers, from 1 to max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the "1.jpg" part at all, and all you want is the suffix and the part before the suffix, you can do what you have above (the second one) to get the prefix, and simply concatenate the prefix and suffix to get the answer you're looking for.

The split call might be overkill but it will do the job.

Comment: `filename = filename.Split(New String() {suffix}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0) + suffix` - Sorry, just added as comment for less advanced programmers like me some weeks ago :) (replace the "+" by "&" if you dont use Option Strict and Option Explicit)

Comment: So sorry for delay on accepting answer. I appreciate your simple suggestion, as it's perfectly valid for what I was needing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim suffix As String = "_version"
        Dim searchThis As String = "something_version1.png"
        MsgBox(GetPrefix(suffix, searchThis))
    End Sub
    Function GetPrefix(suffix As String, searchThis As String) As String
        Dim suffixLocation As Integer = searchThis.IndexOf(suffix) + suffix.Count
        Return searchThis.Substring(0, suffixLocation)
    End Function
End Class
```